# «Até» or «a onde» in this context?

Tags: gramática, preposições

> - Eu me dirijo até os meus filhos moram para levá-los ao parque.
> - Eu me dirijo a onde os meus filhos moram para levá-los ao parque.

Which preposition is correct in that context? Do some say "a onde" and the others say "até", or are both of them used?

Comment: I'd say either "Eu me dirijo até ONDE os meus filhos moram para LEVÁ.LOS ao parque" ou "Eu me dirijo aonde os meus filhos moram para LEVÁ.LOS ao parque." at least for European Portuguese

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I agree; a third form could be `(...) para OS LEVAR ao parque`.

Comment: Não se diz "me dirijo aonde" e sim "me dirijo para onde", pelo menos em pt-BR é mais comum, até um "pra onde" soa melhor

Comment: acho estranho esse uso de dirigir. Será que não seriaL eu vou de carro?

Comment: Dirigir no uso pronominal tem outro sentindo: me dirijo ao meu chefe quando tenho perguntas. Vou de carro até onde os meus filhos moram. Se for ir de carro, o uso pronominal fica errado....na minha opinião.

Comment: Do you mean drive a car? If, dirigir-se would be really weird. I guess no one noticed this.....

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 I've added more explanations to my answer. If you'd like translations of my examples just let me know.

Comment: @Jacinto please so I can better comprehend how the grammar goes. Obrigado, cara :)

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Done.

Comment: Muito obrigado, guri

Answer (score 6):

Let’s get two little things out of the way first. You don’t write or say *levar-os*: *levar + os* becomes *levá-los*. And you don’t write *a onde* separately: you write *aonde*. Now the important thing: you need *onde* in both sentences: so your choice really is between ***até*** and ***a*** (and *a* merges with *onde* to form a single word):

> (a) Eu me dirijo ***até onde*** os meus filhos moram para levá-los ao parque.
>
> (b) Eu me dirijo ***aonde*** os meus filhos moram para levá-los ao parque.

Now both sentences are correct, meaning “I go to where my children live to take them to the park.” But they are not particularly idiomatic. From now on bear in mind that I’m from Portugal, and what sounds more idiomatic to me may not always sound more idiomatic to a Brazilian.

If I had to choose one of the two sentences I’d go for (b) because *me dirijo até* sounds particularly odd to me; *me dirijo a* is a lot more idiomatic (in Google Books *me dirijo a/à/ao* beats *me dirijo até* 85 to 1).

But even *me dirijo a (some place)* may not be what you’re looking for. *Dirijo* is present indicative, and, as with most verbs, you do not usually use the present indicative of *dirigir* to refer to what you’re doing right now; you can use it instead of the *pretérito perfeito* to tell a story of something that has already happened. So your sentence actually sounds like part of a larger story, as in the following examples (modern spelling; my emphasis):

> Ao receber essa comunicação, ***dirijo-me*** à casa do juiz de paz […] mas sua senhora, assegurando-me estar ele mal de saúde, não me permitiu que com ele falasse. ***Dirijo-me*** à casa do tenente-coronel Joaquim Francisco Gomes de Castro, e o convenço da necessidade de acabar […]  [[*Anais do parlamento Brasileiro*, 1861]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=-x1EAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA119&dq=%22dirijo-me%20a%20casa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCgoXp3LTMAhXJUhQKHRMID-sQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22dirijo-me%20a%20casa%22&f=false) [As I receive that communication, I set off/go to the house of the justice of the peace […] but his wife, assuring me of his ill health, did not allow me to talk to him. I go to the house of lieutenant-colonel Joaquim Francisco Gomes de Castro, and convince him of the need to finish […]]
>
> **Na cidade de Machu-Picchu** ― Digo adeus a Cusco, e, às dez da manhã, ***dirijo-me*** à estação de caminhos de ferro. A carruagem é banal, mas correta. [[Maria Assunção Avillez, *Viagens, Almas e Vidas*, 2004.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=CAISAQAAIAAJ&q=%22dirijo-me%20%C3%A0%20esta%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22dirijo-me%20%C3%A0%20esta%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW5vW50rnMAhXsIcAKHSIJCDAQ6AEIKzAC) [**In the city of Machu-Picchu**  ― I say good bye to Cusco, and, at 10 am, go to the railway station. The coach is ordinary but decent.]

To tell someone what you’re doing right now, you can say *estou me dirigindo* or you can use *vou*. Unlike most verbs we use the verb *ir* to describe what you’re doing right now or are about to do.

In your context *vou a* and *vou até* work equally well. Generally I’d say in this context *vou até* suggests you can take your time to get to your children’s, and once you get there you can hang around for a while before taking them to the park. *Vou a* is neutral: it suggests neither that you can take your time nor that you’re in a hurry (but is compatible with both). *Vou até* sounds particularly natural in situations like these:

> Estou farto de estar em casa: ***vou até*** ao café. [I'm fed up of staying at home: I'm going to the café.]
>
> Apetece-me passear um bocado: ***vou até*** à baixa. [I feel like walking around a bit: I'm going to downtown.]

Note that in these sentences you could also say *vou ao café, vou à baixa*. (In Brazilian Portuguese you can say *até ao café* or *até o café*; in European Portuguese, only *até ao café*; same thing with *até à/até a*.) *Até* also sounds particularly natural if you mean ‘up to (but not beyond)’, in which case it does not matter whether you can take your time or not:

> Todos os dias faço uma grande caminhada: ***vou até*** ao fim da praia e depois volto pela mata. [I go for a long walk everyday: I go to end of the beach, and then come back though the woods.]
>
> ***Vou contigo até*** à Praça da República, mas aí tu viras à esquerda e eu tenho que virar à direita. [I'll go with you as far as Republic Square, but there you turn left, and I have to turn right.]

On a final note about your sentences, even *vou até onde/aonde moram os meus filhos* doesn’t sound particularly idiomatic. Wouldn't *vou a/até casa dos meus filhos* suit your purposes? It sounds a lot better.

Comment: You don't use dirigir to say drive to a place either. It's not ir either. The asker clearly meant: drive.

Comment: @Lambie One of the meanings of *dirigir-se a* is *go to*, whether on foot or by car: «por favor, dirija-se à farmácia mais próxima». *Ir* can be on foot, by car, bicycle, boat, plane, or even on horseback: «vou ao Brasil», «vou à praia», «há projetos para ir a Marte». At any rate, the question is about ***a*** versus ***até***, and whether you go on foot or by car is not important.

Comment: I am fluent in Portuguese. to say: dirija-se à farmácia mais próxima is not the meaning of dirigir used by the OP. The idea was not one of giving someone directions like that. The OP meant: I drive and used the wrong term. Why not just admit it? Fulano não se "dirije" até o lugar onde os filhos morram. Credo. Mas obrigada pelo cursinho. Fulano se dirige às autoridades, isso sim, quando for necessário....

Comment: @Lambie «me dirijo aonde os meu filhos moram» é pouco natural, como eu digo na minha resposta, mas é gramatical, com *me dirijo* interpretado   no mesmo sentido que em «dirija-se à farmácia» ou como neste texto dos [Anais do Parlamento Brasileiro: «ao receber essa comunicação, dirijo-me á casa do juiz de paz»](https://books.google.pt/books?id=-x1EAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA119&dq=%22dirijo-me+a+casa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCgoXp3LTMAhXJUhQKHRMID-sQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22dirijo-me%20a%20casa%22&f=false) (grafia original). Se o OP  quis com *dirigir* dizer uma coisa diferente, só ele o poderá esclarecer.

Comment: Acho que é óbvio que o OP nãi quis usar o verbo no sentido de: to address oneself to or to direct oneself to. Penso o siguinte: drive e dirigir. I drive to where my kids are...e colocou dirigir. Isso tem um nome: tradução literal. Espero  não ter me dirigido ao ar. :)

Comment: @Lambie Editei a resposta, indicando agora o significado de «me dirijo aonde os meus filhos moram». Portanto se o OP pensava que *eu me dirijo* significa *I drive*, fica agora a saber que não.

Answer (score 3):

As preposições indicadas pelo *Dicionário de Verbos e Regimes* de Franscisco Fernandes (45.ª ed.) são *a* e *para*:

> *Pronominal* — Encaminhar-se: "Apenas os viu desaparecer, DIGIRIU-SE *para* Hermengarda." (*Herculano*, Eurico 233.) "DIRIGI-ME *a* um daqueles vultos." (Idem, *apud* Stringari.)

Tem também uma nota no fim, dizendo que no sentido de *endereçar*, *para* deve preceder o lugar e *a* o destinatário. Não é o teu caso, mas de qualquer modo, *para* parece ser a preposição favorita para introduzir lugares com *dirigir*.

O Aulete vai [na mesma direção](http://www.aulete.com.br/dirigir).

Isto não significa que *até* seja impossível. Como diz a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (vol. II, pág. 1555):

> Num uso coloquial e informal, a preposição *até* pode também ter um valor espacial direcional, sem qualquer pressuposição de limite, semelhante ao da preposição *a*:
>
> a. Vem *até* minha casa.
> b. Vou *até ao* café.

O facto de a segunda frase precisar da preposição aparentemente redundante *a* a seguir a *até* é uma particularidade do português, que é comum desde o séc. XVII.

Consegui encontrar 8 exemplos deste uso no CETEMPúblico:

> - A frase partiu de dentro da sala, em alta voz, no momento em que um empresário se dirigia até ao átrio para tomar um pouco de ar fresco.
> - Aqui há uns tempos, Pi Garcia, surfista, dirigiu-se até à praia para ver como estavam as ondas.

A tua frase tem vários outros problemas:

1. o uso do presente do indicativo (provavelmente querias *estou a dirigir-me* — *me estou dirigindo* no Brasil — ou *vou dirigir-me*),
2. o facto de *dirigir-se*/*encaminhar-se* não ser a escolha mais apropriada,
3. a escrita de *a onde* separadamente (apesar de, de facto, este *aonde* não ser do mesmo tipo que o de *Aonde vais?*),
4. o uso de *levar-o* em vez de *levá-lo* (*para o levar* também seria possível),
5. a primeira frase falta-lhe um *onde*. Repara que o pronome relativo *onde* inicia a oração encaixada *onde os meus filhos moram* em ambos os casos (mesmo quando há a fusão entre *a* e *onde*).

Answer (score 0):

In that context, use the preposition "até".

> Dirijo-me até onde moram meus filhos, para levá-los ao parque.

Comment: Why? And I think "aonde" can also be used: `fui aonde o andor está a ser montado, para ver se precisavam de ajuda`.

Answer (score 0):

IR, VIR, VOLTAR, CHEGAR, CAIR, COMPARECER e DIRIGIR-SE são intransitivos, exigindo a preposição “de”, na
indicação de procedência; a preposição “a”, na indicação de destino; e a preposição “para”, na indicação de
mudança definitiva.

Ex.1: Cheguei de São Paulo hoje, irei a Curitiba amanhã.
Ex.2: Irei para Ribeirão Preto, pois consegui um excelente emprego na UBB.

[enter link description here](http://www.professorsabbag.com.br/arquivos/download/1238167904Regencia_Verbal.pdf%20[professorsabbag%20-%20PDF])

"Eu me dirijo a onde os meus filhos moram para levar-os ao parque."

Pelo conceito:
Eu me dirijo para onde os meus filhos moram para levá-los até o parque.
Eu me dirijo de onde os meus filhos moram para levá-los ao parque.

Comment: Eu me dirijo ao chefe quando vejo problemas....eu vou a minha casa de carro....